# How to remember the username and password in c# using cookie

Tags: c#, asp.net

Am new in c# and i've created a login form with two fields username and password also remember me checkbox.. first time user logged in the form with checked the remember me checkbox.. can u guide me how to generate the users password automatically in password field from cookie when the user logged in next time using c#??

Comment: If you want to prefill the form, you should let the browser store the information for you, instead of keeping it in a cookie.

Comment: You should _never_ store a password in the cookie - it is much too easy to eavesdrop on cookies. Use some sort of expiring token instead.

Answer (score 2):

Hope you are using FormsAuthentication. In the SetAuthCookie method, there is one parameter, PersistCookie, set this value to true, ASP.Net runtime will store the user credentials to the client.

You can find more details here : [How to: Implement Simple Forms Authentication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xdt4thhy.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, what you want is to have the login form prefilled with the login information, the next time the user visits your page.

You should **NOT** use a cookie to do that, for security reasons. The best way to do it is instead to let the browser store the login information for you. I bet your browser has asked you "Save this password? Yes, Never, Not now" before?

To accomplish that, the browser needs to recognize that it is dealing with a login form. I believe there might be some differences between various browsers how they detect that, but following these steps should be sufficient for most browsers I belive:

1. Make sure the input fields are named `username` and `password`
2. Make sure that the password input is of type `password`
3. Make sure that the form has a proper action attribute
4. Make sure that the form has a submit button

Answer (score 0):

Asp.net has an implementation of forms authentication ready to use.

Use the methods FormsAuthentication.SignIn() and FormsAuthentication.SignOut() to create the auth cookie or delete it.

For more info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.aspx